# Bluehost shared IP address Codeigniter ERROR

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, web-hosting, bluehost

I tried to use the BlueHost Shared IP address as my temporary web address using Codeigniter Framework.

The **MAINPAGE** works fine when I open http://69.000.000.000/~glexcorp/example.
The **problem** is when I visit other sub pages, it causing me **404: File Not Found**.

Any problem with the htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: got any solution???